# Is there a way to send a promise from parent controller to child controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my `parentController.js`

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('parentController', parentController);

parentController.$inject = [];

function parentController() {

    init();

    function init() {
        return somePromise();
    }

}
```

Here is my `childController.js`

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('childController', childController);

childController.$inject = [];

function childController() {

    init();

    // need to wait for parentController init to finish
    function init() {
    }

}
```

I need the child controller to wait for parent controller initialization to be done.

I was thinking of using

```
$scope.broadcast();
```

But there always exist a possibility of race condition depending on how long `somePromise` takes.

Is there a way to pass in promise from parent controller to child controller?

Comment: Are you using the $stateprovider?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not what you are trying to achieve, But I believe that you can resolve this using the `resolve` property, like this:

```
.state('app.parent', {
    url: 'parent/',
    views: ...,
    resolve: {
        item: function() {
            return somePromise();
        }
    },
    controller: function(item) {
        item
    }
})

.state('app.parent.child', {
    url: 'child',
    views: ...,
    resolve: {
        itemChild: function(item) {
            //Do something in case is nedeed
            return item;
        }
    },
    controller: function(itemChild) {
        itemChild
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out **angular-ui-router** like stated resolve might be able to help